# Rolling up daily data to weekly with resample and offset in pandas

Tags: pandas, offset, pandas-resample

I have daily covid data that I would like to roll up to weekly. The problem is that I want my weeks to go from Sunday to Saturday, but the default is Mon to Sun. I tried to use loffset, but it's only changing the dates not my data, plus it's adding a date that does not exist in the dataset.

Code:

```
logic = {'iso_code'  : 'first',
         'new_cases'  : 'sum',
         'new_deaths'  : 'sum',
         'icu_patients'   : 'sum',
         'hosp_patients' : 'sum',
         'people_vaccinated': 'sum'} #it's possible to have 'first', 'max','last', etc

offset = pd.offsets.DateOffset(-1)

df_covid_weekly = df_covid_file.resample('W', on='date', label = 'right', loffset=offset).apply(logic).reset_index()
```

Raw Data Snipet:
[image]

Current Outcome:
[image]

Expected Outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets):

```py
df_covid_file.resample('W-SAT', on='date', label = 'right')
```

The offset `W` is equivalent to `W-SUN` ("week ending on Sunday") and `W-SAT` is "week ending on Saturday", and so on.

If you want an offset object you can use `pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5)`, which is equivalent to `W-SAT`.  The offset strings are aliases for these objects.  Sometimes using the objects instead of their string counterparts makes code parametrization a little easier.

Comment: The anchored offset works perfectly. How would I use pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5) as an alternative method?